# Determine whether the Question is One-to-One; f(x) = 3x+4?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a problem understanding how to determine if a function is one to one.

The problem is: Show that the function f(x) = 3x+4 is one-to-one.

Also, I'm being thrown off by the notation x[subset 1] = x[subset 2], what does that mean, loosely speaking? "In my eyes" that would mean two different values are being represented.

Comment: Ah. Okay I see now.

Comment: I think he just means $x_1 = x_2$? As in $f(x_1) = f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$

Answer (score 1):

In general, to show that a function is one to one you would suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$ and show that it must be the case that $x=y$.

In this case you start by assuming that $3x+4=3y+4$ and then proceed to show that $x=y$.

I believe when you say x[subset 1]=x[subset 2] you are actually saying $x_{1}=x_{2}$ which in my answer is just the $x$ and $y$.

[image]

Consider the graph of your function to be more specific. To see that it is a one to one function, you draw a horizontal line and see that the horizontal line never intersects the graph more than once. This tells you that for each value of $x$ your function only takes one value of $f(x)$.

By using the method of proof I described above you are showing that for every value on the $y$ axis you have only one value on the $x$ axis that gives you that value.

Comment: Yes, the notation you used for x1 = x2 is correct; however, I still am not sure if you understand what I mean. Isn't f(x)=f(y) two different functions.

Comment: You are essentially plugging in two "different" values into your function $f$ and then showing that those two values must be the same. $f$ is the function. $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a graph and if there are any values of x for which there are two values of y then the function is not one to one.

Comment: can you do that for $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_0^+, \,f(x)=\begin{cases}{\qquad x; x\in \mathbb Q \\-x; else}\end{cases}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, the mapping in my comment is defined as $f:\mathbb R_0^+ \to \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question of whether a function is one-to-one is answered by whether there is one and only one value of every $f(x)$ for every $x$. Since it can be demonstrated that $f(x)=3x+4$ is linear and continuous (there are no gaps), there is both one and only one value of $3x+4$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, it is one-to-one. Another way is to rearrange the function so that the $x$ is on the left side, and solve for x in terms of $f(x)$. The new equation will be the inverse function. If there is one and only one value of $x$ for every $f(x)$, then the function is indeed one-to-one.